# Proper use of updateOrCreate method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a OnetoOne relationship between insurances table and confirmations table.

Here is the migration for confirmations:

```
$table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('insurance_id')->unsigned()->index()->unique();
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('insurance_id')->references('insurancenumber')->on('insurances');
```

I want to make the status updatable.

There is a form with two buttons of reject and accept and the controller does this:

```
    public function confirmation(){

    $confirm_button = Request::get('confirm_button');
    $reject_button = Request::get('reject_button');
    if (isset($confirm_button)){
        $status = true;
    }else if (isset($reject_button)){
        $status = false;
    }
    Confirmation::updateOrCreate(['insurance_id' => session('insurance_id')],['status'=> $status]);
}
}
```

I want if a confirmations row with the same insurance_id exists, just update it.

It is always setting false on the status. The session has the right value, I checked it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent duplicate entry you check your unique attribute using **unique** validation rules.

Or, you can first check in the database using find or any query builder and then create new instance of model if it's already not exist.

$status variable never reaches the else block. You may need to post the form code for deeper investigation.